# Install RVM with Chef on CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos, rvm, chef-infra

This is what I've got in my recipe so far

```
execute "rvm-install" do
  command "curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable"
  action :run
end

execute "rvm-setup" do
  command "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh"
  action :run
end
```

`rvm-install` passes fine but when running `rvm-setup` I get this:

```
Errno::ENOENT
-------------
No such file or directory - source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```

The file is there, I can run the same command from my terminal.

Why am I getting this error, and how could I resolve this one?

Answer (score 1):

I also thought about trying to bake my own RVM cookbook; however after looking at the [official cookbook](http://rvm.io/integration/chef) I decided against it.  It is flexible enough to either use custom recipes or to drive with node attributes.